Easily unload gravel from pickup truck
I have a road at a backwoods location in Eastern Ontario that has large dips/holes.

The picture doesn't do the road justice. The hole is large and the bumps are bedrock with 1-2 inches of moss and soil on top. Driving truck on rocky trail

I plan to fill my truck (2010 Silverado 1500; 6.5 ft bed) with gravel from a natural sand pit 1km away by hand shovelling.
I will need to unload several gravel loads into the holes in the road. Is there an easy way to unload the gravel instead of hand shovelling it into the hole?
Edit: I'm on a shoestring budget.

I've done exactly this at my riverbottom land several times. Why does it need to be easy? All it takes is a little time, and you get a good core and shoulder workout in the process. (Also, you can precisely locate the fill if you do it a shovelfull at a time; if you just dump it you'll end up moving it anyway.) Folks used to dig entire house basements by hand.

You definitely want gravel. Sand will just squish around and wash away. You need structure and binder.

There are bed unloaders for trucks, if expecting to do this job/similar again.  Some are fancy but some are just a heavy duty sheet you wind up to unload.

@isherwood I'd always thought the same. But it seems to me that most rural roads in Ontario are made of this sand/gravel mixture. It works well for public roads, and it has worked well for me for other road repairs. Even still, I'll use logs and rocks to hold it in.

Gravel contains sand, so I'm not sure what you mean. Gravel without sand is simply crushed rock.

Personally I'd be looking at alternatives to hand shovelling the material in to the truck, surely that's the more difficult process?

@isherwood  You must be working to a different definition to me - if I bought gravel I would expect the vast majority of sand to have been washed away, leaving just the actual gravel, ie small stones.

For holes of this size, you may want to use multiple grades of rubble/hardcore/gravel/sand, starting with the coarsest and finishing with the finest - that's the Macadam principle of road-building.

@ThaRobster It would be nice to rent a mini excavator or skid steer. But the price is cost prohibitive: $1000 for a day, including delivery. I'm on a shoestring budget.

Sorry if this is obvious to everyone but when shoveling a lot of stone, try to switch sides often to balance the 'workout' across both sides of your body.  It's a little awkward to shovel on the non-dominant side but I've managed to mess my neck up (for months) moving gravel. Once you get used to it, doing this can make you faster too.

Try a Tarp that can be pulled out with a crank.

(The link explains it)   I have used them on a friends truck. They work well.
Not expensive, but for the price if it works just a few times it is worth it. Spend a bit of time shopping and you will find them in a heavier design but at a higher price.

Heavy tarp and attach it to a tree the other side of the hole... drive away gently.

Good idea. Those unloaders are surprisingly expensive and hard to come by in Canada.

There is such a thing as a dump trailer you can rent. They're heavy duty and can help you release the sand easily into the hole. Your pickup should be able to tow it easily.

I didn't know those trailers existed. Interesting solution!

I linked Home Depot, but you can often find these at your commercial equipment rentals like United Rentals, etc.

Something like this might be a really good option here, especially because it sounds like you're shoveling the gravel into the bed yourself.

5 gallon buckets are super cheap, so buying a bunch of them isn't too bad. There's still a manual labor element to the whole thing (I'm assuming that's ok, because you're on a budget), but that's going to make sure that most of the gravel ends up in buckets that are easy to grab and dump in the desired area. Shovel off anything that's on top of the buckets that's preventing you from grabbing each bucket, and then start pulling buckets out. After that, anything left that was in between the buckets can be shoveled, or maybe swept out.

This is a very smart idea, ergonomically! :)

Fill it half way up, laying sideways using a spade as a hoe. Then put it in the truck. Repeat, except dump the next one into the half full one. Repeat. Gravel doesn't shovel easily unless it's on a slab and the shovel is flat.

I'd consider hoeing it off the back of the truck from behind, if using your pickup truck was a prerequisite.
I'd consider renting a small dump truck if the pickup truck was not a prerequisite.
Whatever vehicle is used, be sure not to overload it. I'd imagine that off-roading over bumpy land is a lot harder on a loaded vehicle than driving on a flat asphalted road.

On the "not overloading" front, I recommend starting work from the near end of the track, reversing the vehicle to the work site if possible.  Then you're only driving on the part you've already improved, which is kinder on the suspension.

Two options come to mind.

Buy sandbags from a local retailer. These provide for units of carrying that can be filled on the ground, moved into the truck bed (particularly if there is one person in the bed and one handing up bags), and then dumped out of the bed as desired. You don't have to fill them all the way if they get too heavy for you. You get it all in the truck bed in individual containers, filled to be lifted by available personnel. You don't get sand absolutely everywhere in your truck bed. Reusable to boot. Even better, given what looks like a slope with drainage there, you can use some filled sandbags to anchor the downhill side and hold your fill in place much better (might want to get some rocks there eventually to make it more solid).

I'm seeing a variety of fill in close vicinity to the road that might be easier to shovel and throw. Up to you.



I'm not sure how 60 lb. sandbags are easier than a spadeful at a time.

@isherwood - you don't have to fill them all the way. You get it all in the truck bed in individual containers, filled to be lifted by available personnel. You don't get sand absolutely everywhere in your truck bed.

I think, Jon, is meaning the bags only not prefilled ones and for deeper holes emplacing filled ones from the local source  into those cavities and the trail edges may be a more robust use.

Don't fill your bags more than 10-15 kg or so.  The lower end of that is what we use for transferring spoil hand-to-hand in cave exploration, usually in much more awkward spaces than what's pictured.

I have never done something like that but you could get an old sturdy plywood board roughly the size of your truck bed with enough to spare that you can stand between the board and the cabin. Place a hydraulic jack under it and use it to crank the cabin side of the board up to unload easier.
